# Cannot create contact with email address

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Posting to this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts` with this payload:

```
{
  "displayName": "test",
  "givenName": "test",
  "emailAddresses": {
    "address": "test@test.com",
    "name": "test"
  }
}
```

Results in an error:

> Property emailAddresses in payload has a value that does not schema

As far as I can tell this is correct according to the emailAddress resource type https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/emailaddress

clearly I'm doing it wrong, but I don't know what needed to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON syntax is off. `emailAddresses` is a collection, so you need square parentheses. Try something like:

```
{
   {
     "displayName": "test",
     "givenName": "test",
     "emailAddresses": [
       {
          "address": "test@test.com",
          "name": "test"
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

Hope this helps,